# Singlepart to multipart not producing results

Tags: qgis, geometry, splitting, singlepart

I have a line - a street downloaded from OSM.  It is in separate parts geometrically, but is contained in one record in the attribute table.  That means it is only one row.  I would like to split this street into its separate parts (you can see that it is made up of 4 separate lines), but I get this error when I try to run it through Vector > Geometry tools > Singlepart to Multipart.  Why is this happening? Why do I need more than one feature to run this tool?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're using the wrong tool.  You already have a multi-part shape, and want to split it into multiple features. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79274/splitting-discontiguous-vector-feature-in-qgis